# Play framework 2.2 Slick dependency issue

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, importerror

I'm trying to follow [this](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/sql.html) tutorial, but I get stuck as soon as trying to import necessary packages:

```
import scala.slick.session.Database
import Database.threadLocalSession
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
object slick is not a member of package scala
not found: object Database
object slick is not a member of package scala
```

My SBT dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "1.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "0.5.0.8"
)
```

What am I missing here?

I'm running Play Framework 2.2.0, Scala 2.10.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably need to run some of these commands in sbt (in this order):

```
reload
update
eclipse
```

(obviously substitute eclipse with whatever IDE you are using, or remove it if you are not using an IDE.)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. Although I've already found the reason for the problem. The required slick and play-slick jars were not included in "Referenced Libraries" in eclipse. Is that because I only tried "play run" and that doesn't automatically handle sbt?

Comment: No, it's because you didn't type `eclipse` in sbt and then refresh the project in Eclipse.